# Concatenating SQL select statements with an IF EXISTS

Tags: sql, oracle

Apologies if this is a stupid question but I can't get my head around this. I want to only select a value with a colon if it exists, this value being "county". However, I'm not sure whether I am going about this the right way? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT pe.personname AS "Person Name", pe.street||','||pe.town||','||
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT pe.county FROM persons pe WHERE pe.county = '')
    THEN pe.county||','|| 
    ELSE
    END IF
 pe.postcode as "Persons Address"
 FROM persons pe
```

---

Updated version which gives output of multiple commas if there is no county.

```
SELECT personname as "Person Name"
street||','||town||
   CASE county
   WHEN '' THEN ''
   ELSE ','||county
   END
||','||postcode as "Person Address"
from Suppliers;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've gone for this but getting a **missing keyword error**:-

```
 SELECT personname AS "Person Name", 
   street || ',' || town || ',' ||
     CASE WHEN county > ''
     THEN county || ','
     ELSE ''
     END 
   || postcode AS "Person Address"
 FROM Persons
```

Comment: Added the missing concat operator between the CASE expression and the `postcode`

Comment: It worked but now I have a problem with too many commas. Thanks for your help, I will post an updated answer. If you could give any help that would be great.

Comment: Do you have Nulls in the columns (`country` or others)?

Comment: I don't have any values in them. Does this mean I can't use '' or ' ' or null? If so what can I use instead? Thanks, sorry I'm struggling to get my head round this.

Comment: Small correction (only for the case that `country` has nulls). It will get more complicated if you have nulls in the other columns as well. Is this for Oracle?

Comment: Nope I don't and yes it is :) Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean with a comma.

```
SELECT pe.personname AS "Person Name", pe.street||','||pe.town||
  IF pe.county <> ''
  THEN ','||pe.county
  ELSE ''
  END IF
pe.postcode as "Persons Address"
FROM persons pe
```

It might be cleaner, (and you might have to) do this:

```
SELECT pe.personname AS "Person Name",
  IF pe.county <> ''
  THEN pe.street||','||pe.town||','||pe.county
  ELSE pe.street||','||pe.town
  END IF
pe.postcode as "Persons Address"
FROM persons pe
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with this. It says From keyword not found where expected and an error on line 2

Comment: In which SQL product, can `IF` be used like this? The expression is `CASE WHEN ...THEN ... ELSE ... END`, not `IF ... THEN ... ELSE ... END IF`

Comment: I think I've got it thank you :) I'll let you know if it doesn't work

Comment: Oracle uses both CASE and IF...THEN...END IF.

Comment: @Marlin: I think you are confusing this with the [`IF` statement](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/if_then.php). I don't think there is an `IF` expression. There is both a `CASE` statement and a `CASE` expression though.

Comment: Could be.  I never or rarely use them.  Mostly I have seen examples on Stackoverflow.  I have found on Oracle's site, "Starting in Oracle 9i, you can use the case statement within an SQL statement. It has the functionality of an IF-THEN-ELSE statement."

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get two columns one being the persons name, and the second being the address part, I would:

```
    select pe.personname, pe.street || ',' || pe.town || ',' || 
(case county when not null then (county || ',') else '' end), postcode
```

use a case statement to evaluate the county, if there is one insert it with the ',' else ''